# Angular, как вызвать функцию с аргументом

Tags: javascript, angular

Не могу разобраться, если вызывать this.varCount в качестве переменной у функции draw - в консоль выводит то что надо, а в DOM не хочет выводить:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: ` <p>Count: {{ varCount }}</p> `,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  varCount = 0;
  startInterval: NodeJS.Timeout;

  ngOnInit() {
    const draw = (count: number) => {
      const start = () => {
        count++;
        console.log(count);

        if (count >= 100) {
          clearInterval(this.startInterval);
        }
      };
      this.startInterval = setInterval(start, 0);
    };

    draw(this.varCount);
  }
}
```

Но если вызывать this.varCount внутри самой функции, всё работает как надо

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: ` <p>Count: {{ varCount }}</p> `,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  varCount = 0;
  startInterval: NodeJS.Timeout;

  ngOnInit() {
    const draw = () => {
      const start = () => {
        this.varCount++;
        console.log(this.varCount);

        if (this.varCount >= 100) {
          clearInterval(this.startInterval);
        }
      };
      this.startInterval = setInterval(start, 0);
    };

    draw();
  }
}
```

Но мне нужно именно через переменную вызывать, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: а чем тебя не устраивает второй вариант? =) он же рабочий и правильный)

Comment: @overthesanity, там просто много чего ещё надо в функцию передавать и вызывать с разными аргументами. Я просто очень сильно сократил код и выделил суть проблемы

Comment: почитай комментарий @yugofx под ответом, он там все изложил в чем основная суть и почему твой код не работает первый

Comment: @overthesanity, прочитал, но не понял как это пофиксить, чтобы туда передавалось значение, а не ссылка. И не понял почему у меня varCount перестал быть значением, а стал ссылочным типом

Comment: мне кажется, или тебе стоит ознакомиться с основами JSа прежде чем учить фреймворки? =) просто это досконально изложено на learn javascript в курсе работы с функциями

Comment: @overthesanity, действительно :D 
[ссылка](https://learn.javascript.ru/function-basics#parametry) 
`Когда функция вызывается в строках (*) и (**), переданные значения копируются в локальные переменные from и text. Затем они используются в теле функции.`
говнокодю уже года 3)))

Answer (score -1):

У вас `this` теряется во вложенной функции `draw`

```
  varCount = 0;
  startInterval: NodeJS.Timeout;

  ngOnInit() {
    let self = this
    const draw = () => {
      const start = () => {
        self.varCount++;
        console.log(self.varCount);

        if (self.varCount >= 100) {
          clearInterval(this.startInterval);
        }
      };
      this.startInterval = setInterval(start, 0);
    };

    draw();
  }
```

Comment: так у него второй вариант работает и без копирования ссылки `this` в `self` :)

Comment: да? Я не проверял просто))

Comment: @RavenTheX нигде `this` не теряется. просто надо различать передачу аргументов в функцию по значению и по ссылке. В первом варианте передается значение, а во втором просто сразу изменяется поле класса. Плюс, создание стрелочных функций происходит сразу с "прибитым" контекстом. Поэтому и первый вариант бы работал, если бы не абсолютно ненужная передача параметра